# want to store files of specific type in a ArrayList<File> and then want to delete them permanently from sd-card

Tags: android

It is not deleting file when i use
"deleteFile(String);"

```
ArrayList<String> record=new ArrayList<String>();
{
//searching files and storing it in in record
}

{
//Delete all the files stored in record permanently on the click of a Button 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
File sfile = new File(file.getAbsolutePath());
File mkdir = new File("/root/video");
mkdir.mkdir();

File dfile = new File(mkdir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" +  sfile.getName());

try {
    if (!dfile.exists())
        dfile.createNewFile();
    else
        dfile.delete();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

you have to store full file path in arraylist and than use that path

Comment: i have a list of files, almost 20+ files. so shall i store them in ArrayList<String> or List<FIle>? and then how to delete them?

Comment: make a List <File> and from above code you can see the statement for delete file dFile.delete();